# Where can I find the right printer driver for my Epson Stylus Photo 1400?

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 and am new to Linux. I have this great Epson Stylus Photo 1400 printer which I love because it prints great quality photos and furthermore it can do wide format. But since I ditched windows and went with ubuntu I haven't been able to print to my epson. (my hp deskjet works fine though)

When i first plugged in the epson to my laptop it 'found' the new hardware and seemed to install it but wouldn't print to it. I have searched for other drivers and tried them but to no avail. Found one on the epson site - epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.2.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb - but it didn't work either.
the printer shows up in my hardware list and the print job shows up in the queue, but nothing ever prints.

Does anybody know why this is happening? Remember I am new to linux, so is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got a driver from Epson's site for my Epson Stylus NX130 printer/scanner and it works well.   I would double check you downloaded the correct driver as that part of their site is a bit messy to navigate I think.

Answer (score 1):

A possible alternative is the (commercial) Turboprint drivers, the supported printers currently include the Epson Stylus Photo 1400

[Turboprint supported Epson printers](http://www.turboprint.info/printers_Epson.html)

Answer (score 1):

Effective 20 January 2013, AVASYS no longer provides drivers for Epson printers. New source for such files is: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/

Answer (score 0):

[Avasys Epson/Linux Driver Page](http://avasys.jp/eng/linux_driver/)

Just click on the Inkjet icon at the bottom of that page, select your model on the next page. Scroll down to the bottom again for either the i386 (32-bit) or x86_64 (64-bit) .deb file depending on which version you require. The downloaded .deb file should install nicely, I've never had a problem with their drivers.

EDIT: Avasys only recently added 64-bit drivers to their list, so I think they've done a bit of house-cleaning on their drivers. If you had problems in the past, they may be fixed now.